# The set of non-conjugate elements

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, representation-theory

I have $H \leq G$ where $G$ is a group. 
Now for any $t \notin H$ we have $H \cap tHt^{-1} = e$

Now $N$ is a set of all elements of $G$ which are not conjugate to any element of $H$

I want to understand the structure of $N$

I am supposed to show that $|N| = |G|/|H| - 1 $ so I thought of using class equation on the group $G$ but unable to proceed.

Please help

Comment: What you wrote is not too clear. I think you mean that $N$ is *the* (and not *a*) set of all elements of $G$ such and such. Correct? Also, what you write in the first line is in generally false. So are you *assuming* that $H$ is a subgroup with trivial intersection with its conjugates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, the number of conjugates of a subgroup $H$ of $G$ equals index$[G:N_G(H)]$, where $N_G(H)=\{t \in H : H^t=H\}$ is the *normalizer* of $H$ in $G$. Since $H \cap H^t = 1$ for all $t \notin H$, it follows that $N_G(H)=H$, since $H$ is non-trivial.

The elements that are conjugate to some element of $H$ is exactly the set $\bigcup_{t \in T} H^t$, where $T$ is a transversal set of the left cosets of $N_G(H)=H$. Since every pair of different $H$-conjugates intersects trivially we have $|\bigcup_{t \in T} H^t|= |T|(|H|-1)+1=\text{index}[G:H](|H|-1)+1=|G|-\frac{|G|}{|H|}+1$. Hence $|N|=|G| - |\bigcup_{t \in T} H^t|=\frac{|G|}{|H|}-1$, as desired.

Answer (score 0):

Compute the number of conjugate subgroups $H$ has, and show each pair of these conjugate subgroups intersects trivially. Use this information to compute the size of the union of these conjugates, and then you can determine the size of the union's complement.

Comment: @SMath Where are you stuck?

Comment: Number of conjugate subgrops of $H$ will be $|G|-|H|$ so ...

Comment: @SMath Nope, that is the size of $G\setminus H$, it is not the number of subgroups conjugate to $H$. Computing the number of conjugate subgroups is a standard exercise. (Use the orbit-stabilizer theorem.)

Comment: No. You already said what $N$ is: it is the set of all elements which are not conjugate to any element of $H$. My answer is suggesting you do the "opposite problem" of computing the number of elements of $G$ that *are* conjugate to an element of $G$, or in other words to compute the size of the union of all conjugates of $H$. I explained in my answer how to go about doing that. If you need any help, just ask, but be sure to specify what it is you need help with.